# Allowing user to edit only the page content and some custom fields in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This is the site:

http://www.backpackers.rs

Using "User Role Editor" i have user group that can only read and edit published pages so i can have as many users as i want in that user group and they all will have only one published page on their own so they can edit only that page.

Now, this is how a user in that user group currently is seeing "edit page" page:

http://i39.tinypic.com/rwuesh.png

What i need is to disable all those things that have a red border around it + something with custom fields. So i need to disable these things for user in that user group:

1. ability to change status of the page
2. entire "Attributes" block is something that he/she **must not** see or be able to change
3. ability to change something in "Discussion" block
4. he/she shouldnt see "Page revisions" block
5. **i need a way to give those users ability to use only some custom fields**. Currently we have 6 custom fields, and i want to give these users ability to only use 4 of those custom fields.
6. i need to disable these users from creating new custom fields.

I dont need complete answers for these things, something to get me started is really what i need. I have been reading codex a lot, but still didnt find something to help me with this, so basically any answer is more then appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted this link before, but check out the [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) plugin. It allows you to disable practically anything in WordPress for users. It does so based on the user's role.

Comment: Thanks! I started using "Magic fields" + "User role editor" and that solved most of my problems, now with Adminimize i think i will solve them all... :) Again thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Check out PodsCMS (http://www.podscms.org/) and use it with Adminimize a long with it. PodsCMS eclipses Magic fields and the standard custom fields used in WordPress. It's simple, scalable, and provides nifty things, like caching! :)